# adding nav controllor to tabbar controllor iPhone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tabbar controllor and trying to add navigation to each control. In xcode 3 i was able to change the controllor to nav controllor in attribute inspection. How do we do that in xcode 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to drag and drop the navigation controller to the tabbar controllor to get the navigation supported tab. Then set the appropriate view controller class.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this. You can either do it in the IB or just allocate a view controller for specific tabs. na. Just do these.

1. Just create new classes as a subclass of Navigation Controller
2. Go to the specific tabs in the IB, and assign their class as the respective class for it's view.
   For example. For Tab 1, click tab1 and select the class as `MyNavigationController` (which should be a subclass of `UINavigationController`).

Comment: I followed the second approach. I added a subclass and the nav bar appears in the tab but no content appears from that view? I have label, its not showing up.

Comment: If the Nav Bar shows on top, it means it's working properly. As far as the label is concerned. Did you connect the outlets for `label` and `view` ?

Comment: when I am subclassing to nav controllor (@interface try1 : UINavigationController) labels are not showing up. When changed to viewcontroller(@interface try1 : UIViewController) it shows up. My label just have statis text.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw `watch this tutorial` Should clear all doubts !!!

Comment: I went through that tutorial already. I did a previous project using a tabbar with nav controllor. I upgraded my xcode and in the attribute inspector you dont find that dropdrop to pick the controllor. Thats the problem I have.